# how to insert a form post data into database in yii 1 framework

Tags: php, yii

this is my form in view

```
<div class="form">
```

```
<?php echo CHtml::errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Your Name'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'regname') ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Your Password'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'regpass') ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Email Address'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'regemail') ?>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'Contact'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activePasswordField($model,'regcontact') ?>
</div>

<div class="row submit">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>
```

please help me to save this data from my controller to model 
this is my model
//-- set Table

```
public function tableName(){
    return 'user';
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
        {
          return array(
        'username'=>'Your username for the game',
        'password'=>'Your password for the game',
         'email'=>'Needed in the event of password resets',
                );
        }
```

and this is my controller

```
public function actionRegister2()
    {
        $model=new RegisterForm;
        if(isset($_POST['RegisterForm']))
        {
            echo 'done';
        }
        $this->render('register2',array(
                'model'=>$model,
            ));
```

i an new in yii framework so didn't get a good tutorial for it, please suggest me how i insert the data into database by submitting a form

Comment: you can refer this site url for **CRUD Operation in YII Version 1** https://www.sitepoint.com/build-a-crud-app-with-yii-in-minutes/ and other link for **CRUD Operation** http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/61723-crud-generator-in-yii/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this code in your controller:

```
public function actionRegister2()
{
     $model=new RegisterForm;
     if(isset($_POST['RegisterForm']))
     {
         $model->attributes = $_POST['RegisterForm'];
         if ($model->save()) {
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success', 'You have successfully added.');
            $this->redirect(array('index'));
        }
         // or if(!$model->save()){ print_r($model->getErrors())} 
    }
    $this->render('register2',array(
                    'model'=>$model,
           )); 
}
```

Comment: got error :-RegisterForm and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "save".

D:\xampp\htdocs\sid\framework\base\CComponent.php(266)

Comment: Look you have to extend it to CActiveRecord because save() is a function in CActiveRecord.

Comment: how to resolve this?    Property "CEmailValidator.0" is not defined.

Comment: onsubmit showing username and password are blank .. why?

Comment: have you tried to print echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);in action??

Comment: Array
(
    [RegisterForm] => Array
        (
            [regname] => demo
            [regpass] => demo
            [regemail] => ooooo
            [regcontact] => 0000000000000
        )

    [yt0] => Register
)  but data table column remain blank during save

Comment: hey look in your form.php i have not seen any of your attributes define model. Also you should have rules define in your model for attributes if you hae no specific rules then you should have define them as safe in rules.

Comment: public function rules()
 {
  return array(
   // username and password are required
   array(['regname', 'regpass', 'regemail', 'regcontact'], 'required'),   
   
  );
 }
 
 //-- set Table
 public function tableName(){
    return 'user';
 }

 public function attributeLabels()
        {
          return array(
    'regname'=>'Your username',
    'regpass'=>'Your password',
    'email'=>'Your Email',
    'contact'=>'Your Contact Number',  
                );
        }